# JavaScript scroll to div with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a PhoneGap application that when it opens an HTML page, I want it to scroll to a specific `<div>` element. So far I've been able to make it do that with this script using jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).delegate('.ui-page', 'pageshow', function () {
     var offset = $(this).find('#timeindicatordiv').offset().top;
     setTimeout(function () {
        $.mobile.silentScroll(offset);
        }, 0);
     });
</script>
```

This only gives me a jump directly to the `<div>` which looks a bit choppy.

Is there any way to give this a smooth animation?

Comment: have you tried this plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/Scrollorama/?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var scrollToElement = function(el, ms){
    var speed = (ms) ? ms : 600;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
    }, speed);
}

// specify id of element and optional scroll speed as arguments
scrollToElement('#timeindicatordiv', 600);
```

jsfiddle/example: http://jsfiddle.net/dtR34/4/

Comment: This works great, accept it allways scrolls to the bottom. How do I control how far it scrolls?

Comment: @LudwigKristoffersson you pass the `scrollToElement` function the `id` of the element you want to scroll to. In the example I gave you the `#timeindicatordiv` element is at the bottom of the page so it's scrolling to that.

Comment: Your previous answer looked better I think :)

Comment: I rolled it back and have provided an example in the fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: offset}, 600);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.click').click(function(l){
   // prevent default action

   l.preventDefault();

   scrollToElement( $(this).attr('href'), 2000 );
});

var scrollToElement = function(el, ms){
    var speed = (ms) ? ms : 2000;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(el).offset().top
    }, speed);
}
```

```css
div {
    margin-top:1000px;
}
div:last-child {
    padding-bottom:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#link1" class="click">link 1</a><br />
<a href="#link2" class="click">link 2</a><br />
<a href="#link3" class="click">link 3</a><br />


<div id="link1">Link 1</div>
<div id="link2">Link 2</div>
<div id="link3">Link 3</div>
```

Comment: Please consider including an explanation of what your code does. While the code may solve the problem, code-only answers are generally not very useful to the wider public.