# How can I force browser to follow a div which is going to be shown?

Tags: jquery, html, interface

A `<div>` or a `<pre>` on the bottom of the page, is going to be toggled/shown by:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slice_img").click(function(){
    $("#slice_pre").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

and a text will appeared on the bottom.

How can I automatically chase and follow the text which is going to be shown by the browser so that the user, himself, won't need to scroll down to see the newly-appeared text?

- I don't want to scroll down to end of the page! I want the browser to follow the exact text, while it is slowly slide down in order to get appeared.

You may (!) understand better by the picture.
[image]

Comment: I am sorry and I know that it might be a little hard to understand. Ask me if you don't understand the problem.

Comment: Are you asking for something similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498517/javascript-scroll-to-div-with-animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work (if I understand correctly):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bvymjpea/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slice_img").click(function(){
    $("#slice_pre").slideToggle("slow", function() { // add a callback function to slideToggle
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#slice_pre").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

Though you probably should be using classes instead of ID's to make this reusable. Your code would then become:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".slice_img").click(function(){
    $(".slice_pre", $(this)).slideToggle("slow", function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bvymjpea/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is even better than what I expected to achieve!

Comment: but I think there is a problem. Scroll-bar disappeared.

Comment: This code wouldn't make the scroll bar disappear. Can you show an example?

Comment: Please excuse me, the problem happened because of overflow: hidden; not by your code! your code is fine! Thank you!