# No user interaction for scrollToElement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to create a webpage that scrolls on a continuous loop from one element to the next without any user interaction. I have searched and it looks like scrollToElement is what I'm looking for (in fact the fiddle from [this answer on another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498517/javascript-scroll-to-div-with-animation) is similar but does have user interaction). Unfortunately everything seems to be done by click or doesn't loop. I'm fairly new to JS but I feel like it should be doable. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the markup of whatever you've tried and give us more details on what you're trying to do? You just want to scroll to a few elements and loop back up and repeat infinitely or what?

Comment: Yes, I am just looking for when the page loads to have a set interval to scroll from one element down the page to the next and then scroll back to the top and begin again. So far I haven't tried much because I'm unsure where to start. Really, I'm not looking for the direct code, but guidance on where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example with jQuery using `setInterval()` and `$.animate()` to scroll to sections.

```js
var $sections = $('section'),
    count = 1,
    speed = 250,
    delay = 2000;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $sections.eq(count).offset().top
  }, speed);
  count = (count + 1) % $sections.length;
}, delay)
```

```css
section {
  height: 200vh;
  background: red;
}
section:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
}
section:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Works like a charm!

Comment: @Acedrew no sweat!

Answer (score 2):

How about creating a function that calls scrollToElement and then setting it as a CB function in the setInterval(). read more:[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Comment: I like this, thanks for pointing me to setInterval(). Could I set it to an array that includes the ID of each element I want to cycle through?