# Scroll on button click to div with specific ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

Have a quite simple code:

```
<button id="div1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">button1</button>
<button id="div2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">button2</button>

<div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width: 100px">
        Text for div 1
</div>
<br/>
<div id="div2" style="height: 1000px; width: 100px">
        Text for div 2
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function reply_click(clicked_id) {

     $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(clicked_id).offset().top
     }, 2000);

}

</script>
```

**Need to scroll after button click to specific div with same id like have button:**

- If clicked button with `id="div2"` so scroll to div with same id (`id="div2"`)
- If we click button `id="div1"` it scrolls to div with `id="div1"`

My code doesn't work. Seems like `scrollTop:` doesn't see div ID it needs to scroll.
But JavaScript function see variable `clicked_id` (could make simple `alert(clicked_id);`) and it works.

Also if I define manually div ID to scroll `scrollTop: $('#div1').offset().top` it works and scrolling to div1, so it means, that function works.

I know, that there is much more simple ways to make it but I need to:

- Start scrolling by **button click**, not just by link (mean not `<a href="#div1">click<a>`)
- Scroll to div with same ID lake have button
- Work it by JavaScript

I am not so clever in JavaScript...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript scroll to div with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19498517/javascript-scroll-to-div-with-animation)

Comment: It is invalid to have two elements with the same id. Just put the id in the `onclick` attribute. I.e., `onclick="reply_click('div1')"`. Make sure you update your jQuery so it works though: `$("#" + clicked_id).offset().top`...

Comment: Heretic Monkey, 
thank you!
it looks like it solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you can use hashes. And why do you need to use JS? If it's not required, you shouldn't use it unnecessarily.

EDIT: Or do you not want to display it in the URL? ("...#div1")

```html
<a href="#div1">button1</a>
<a href="#div2">button2</a>

<div id="div1" style="height: 1000px; width: 100px">
        Text for div 1
</div>
<br/>
<div id="div2" style="height: 1000px; width: 100px">
        Text for div 2
</div>
```

EDIT (JS):

```js
function reply_click(id) {
   document.querySelector(`#${id}`).scrollIntoView();
}
```

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, I know the much more easier way to do it, for example your one.

And yes, I don't want to show div parameter in URL, Also I don't want it through standard link, need to work it by BUTTON click, not on link click. Have some reasons on it.

But on first, I need to do it throught button click, not from by link. And second, by JavaScript. .

Comment: or like so: `document.getElementById("thisIsTheEndMyFriend").scrollIntoView();`